# Is it possible to center Internet Explorer scrollbar arrows?

Tags: html, css, angular, internet-explorer

I am currently working on the IE scrollbar using CSS and I am aware of the scrollbar-face-color, scrollbar-base-color, etc but I was wondering if it is possible to center the arrows? The arrows in the buttons show up in a strange position and if there are any tricks to center them vertically, that would be great.
Thanks

Comment: What's your Internet Explorer version? Try to upgrade the IE Browser version to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want granular control over scroll bar appearance, perhaps something like this would help? https://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/

I like that approach because you can get the same UX across browsers.

Good luck!